# python tkinter polygon scaling

Tags: python, tkinter, polygon, tkinter-canvas

Im trying to add a rescaling function to the polygon I created like so:

```
polygon = None
def polygon(event):
    global polygon
    polygon = my_canvas.create_polygon([150, 75, 225, 0, 300, 75, 225, 150], outline='gray', fill='gray', width=2)
    print(polygon)

def resizePolygon(event):
    my_canvas.scale(poly, 20, 20, 100, 100)
    my_canvas.pack()
```

resizePolygon makes the polygon disappear instead of resizing the polygon, how do I resize the polygon?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the center `(x, y)` of the bounding box of the polygon and use them as the `xOrigin` and `yOrigin` in `.scale()`.

Also better use smaller `xScale` and `yScale` to see the result, `100` is a bit large.

```py
def resizePolygon(event):
    # get the bounding box of the polygon
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = my_canvas.bbox(polygon)
    # calculate the center (x, y) in the bounding box
    cx, cy = (x1+x2)/2, (y1+y2)/2
    # scale the polygon
    my_canvas.scale(polygon, cx, cy, 10, 10) # use scale 10 instead of 100 to see the effect
    #my_canvas.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

`<tkinter.Canvas>.scale(xscale, yscale, xoffset, yoffset)`
From [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20201108093851/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.scale-method):

Resizes matching items by scale factor. The coordinates for each item are recalculated as ((coord-offset)*scale+offset); in other words, each item first moved by -offset, then multiplied with the scale factor, and then moved back again. Note that this method modifies the item coordinates; you may loose precision if you use this method several times on the same items.

I think that you scaled up your polygon by a factor of 20 and moved it 1900 pixels away in both the x and y directions so it disappeared out of your screen. Also that method resizes the whole canvas not the polygon.

Try using: `<tkinter.Canvas>.coords(object, *new_coords)`